What is the correct way to create a mask for decimal numbers in Windows Forms?
$txtValue = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox
Using the mask $txtValue.Mask = "999,999,999.9999" doesn't allow me to enter, for example, 1.333 without typing 000,000,001.333 (or clicking directly at the correct position, but that's impractical). The mask $txtValue.Mask = "000,000,000.00" has almost the same issue.
I tried adding event functions, but it only edits the first number and fails:
$txtValue.add_TextChanged({ 
    $mytxt = $txtValue.Text 
    $txtValue.remove_TextChanged($thisEvent) 
    $myValue.Text = [double]::Parse($mytxt)
    $txtShareValue.add_TextChanged($thisEvent)
})

I also tried using the regex [^0-9.] and slicing the range if the text exceeds the length limit during an event, but this doesn't prevent entering multiple consecutive periods.

It looks like you're looking for string formatting on your double value like: '{0:0##,###,###.####}' -f 1.333. Unclear how 1.333 becomes ...001.3332 (where is that 2 coming from) ?

@SantiagoSquarzon The MaskedTextBox.Mask property uses a different syntax than .NET Numeric Formatting Strings which it says is in-fact derived from VB6, wow.

I'm unsure why you're using MaskedTextBox at all - it's intended for fixed-length, fixed-format text strings, not numeric values - for that you'd use NumericUpDown (which allows for direct input with formatting, and you can hide the up/down spinner buttons too, if you like).

@Dai What I was suggesting in my prev. comment, instead of using a Mask just parse and string formatting: $myValue.Text = '{0:0##,###,###.####}' -f [double]::Parse($mytxt)

The notes here can be useful. The mask definition in the question has ~the opposite functionality, though, but the properties described are the same. As mentioned, you can most probably make use of the NumericUpDown Control instead, if the masked text has no specific meaning, i.e., it's just numeric input

The provisional solution was to use it as you indicated:
$txtValue.Minimum = 0
$txtValue.DecimalPlaces = 2
$txtValue.Maximum = 100000000
$txtValue.Controls[0].Visible = $false

Unfortunately, this object still allows more than one comma or dot (which doesn’t make sense, since it’s a numeric type object), but nothing that can’t be solved by using the add events.
An aside off-topic: I just found it annoying that VSCode doesn’t have a way to show all the attributes and methods of these objects.
